# Modules and Accessing Variables from Modules (Ruby Language)

Tags: ruby, variables, module, instantiation

I have the following Module which has 1 variable which contains a string for the first day of a hypothetical year, 1 method which outputs a string and another method which also outputs a string:

```
module Week
  first_day = "Sunday"

  def weeks_in_month
    puts "There are 4 weeks in a month"
  end

  def weeks_in_year
    puts "There are 52 weeks in a year"
  end
end
```

I now have a class who's only purpose is to print out the variable located in the module.(this is just for testing purposes)

```
class Decade
  include Week

  def firstday
    puts Week::first_day
  end
end
```

I now instantiate Decade and access the methods located in the module using Decades object. My program runs into a problem when calling the firstday method

```
z = Decade.new
z.weeks_in_month
z.weeks_in_year

z.firstday #Errors here
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `first_day' for Week:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I am new to Ruby and am just getting used to Modules, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget to format code with the `{}` button or four spaces of indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing a module the convention is to declare constants like this:

```
module Week
  FIRST_DAY = 'Sunday'
end
```

Note that they're in `ALL_CAPS`. Anything that begins with a capital letter is treated as a constant. Lower-case names of that sort are treated as local variables.

Generally it's bad form to access the constants of another module, it limits your ability to refactor how those are stored. Instead define a public accessor method:

```
module Week
  def first_day
    FIRST_DAY
  end
end
```

Now you can call that externally:

```
Week.first_day
```

Note you can also change how that's implemented:

```
module Week
  DAYS = %w[
    Sunday
    Monday
    Tuesday
    ...
    Saturday
  ]

  def first_day
    DAYS.first
  end

  extend self # Makes methods callable like Week.first_day
end
```

The nice thing about that is the `first_day` method does exactly the same thing, no other code has to change. This makes refactoring significantly easier. Imagine if you had to track down and replace all those instances to `Week::FIRST_DAY`.

There's some other things to note here. The first is that any time you call `include` on a `module` then you get the methods *and* constants loaded in locally. The second thing is when you define a mix-in module, be careful with your names to avoid potential conflict with the target class.

Since you've mixed it in, you don't need the namespace prefix, just calling `first_day` should do it.

Comment: Ah, I thought capital letters for constants was just a convention, but I am guessing that it is actual syntax and thus that is why it did not compile. I come from a java background where defining a value in between the class definition and constructors are automatically considered class variables and not necessarily local variables, hence the confusion with Ruby. Thank You for the input.